# DropDownlist onchange event in javascript no firing for dropdownlist inside Update Panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu, updatepanel, onchange

I have a dropdownlist inside Update Panel, where i load data inside dropdownlist from server side on button click.
Now i have a document.getElementById('dropdownlist').onchange event handler in javascript that is not getting called on selecting values from javascript.

Without using update panel it works fine. But then the entire page gets posted back on button click for loading data inside dropdown.

Here's the aspx code:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">  
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="From Date:" style="display:inline" Font-Size="12"></asp:Label> &nbsp
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ReadOnly = "false" ></asp:TextBox>
<img src="calender.png" />  &nbsp
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="To Date:" style="display:inline" Font-Size="12"></asp:Label> &nbsp
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ReadOnly = "false" ></asp:TextBox>
<img src="calender.png" style="display:inline"/> &nbsp

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnGetTop20Cust" runat="server" Text="Get Top 20 Customers in the selected date range" onclick="btnGo_Click" /><br /> 
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  ></asp:DropDownList> 
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
document.getElementById('MainContent_DropDownList1').onchange = function () {
             var dropDown = document.getElementById('MainContent_DropDownList1');
             var value = dropDown[dropDown.selectedIndex].value;
             var startDate = document.getElementById('MainContent_TextBox1').value;
             var endDate = document.getElementById('MainContent_TextBox2').value;

             GetData(value, startDate, endDate);
}
```

Comment: can you post your code here?

Comment: pls add your code,so we can check what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the id of dropdown , it may be changed in update panel.

Answer (score 0):

Please add you onchange funcion code within pageLoad() , pageLoad() is called after every UpdatePanel refresh.

```
function pageLoad() {
        document.getElementById('MainContent_DropDownList1').onchange = function () {
             var dropDown = document.getElementById('MainContent_DropDownList1');
             var value = dropDown[dropDown.selectedIndex].value;
             var startDate = document.getElementById('MainContent_TextBox1').value;
             var endDate = document.getElementById('MainContent_TextBox2').value;

             GetData(value, startDate, endDate);
}
    }
```

There are other ways to tackle this problems apart from one that i have described above.
From this [link](http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/) i got an idea very much useful..

ASP.NET AJAX does provide a corresponding event. The Application.Init event fires only one time per page load, and is perfect for onetime initialization tasks. It’s not available through a shortcut function and requires slightly more caution, but serves its purpose:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" /> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  Sys.Application.add_init(function() { 
    // Initialization code here, meant to run once.
  }); 
</script>
```

Note that the call to Application.add_init is placed after the ScriptManager. This is necessary because the ScriptManager injects its reference to MicrosoftAjax.js in that location. Attempting to reference the Sys object before that point will result in a “sys is undefined” JavaScript error.

Answer (score 0):

use code like this

`<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" ClientIDMode="Static">`

then change yor javascript code

`document.getElementById('MainContent_DropDownList1').onchange = function () {}`

to

`$(document).ready(function () {
document.getElementById('DropDownList1').onchange = function () {}
});`

OR
u can change

`<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" onchange="ddlchange(this);" ></asp:DropDownList>`

AND

```
function ddlchange(ddl) 
{
           var value = ddl.value; 
             var startDate = document.getElementById('MainContent_TextBox1').value;
             var endDate = document.getElementById('MainContent_TextBox2').value;
             GetData(value, startDate, endDate);
}
```